# Can't get text from URL

Tags: android, kotlin

I think my question is pretty simple, but I just started my road in android, so it's a big problem right now. Anyway, I want to read text from url, convert it to array and display as ListView.

Here's part of my code:

```
private fun getSongList() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute() {
            val songList =
                URL("https://vivalaresistance.ru/radio/stuff/vlrradiobot.php?type=getPlaylist").readText(
                    Charset.forName("windows-1251")
                )
                    .replace("и&#774;", "й")
                    .replace("И&#774;", "Й")
                    .split("\n").toTypedArray()
        }
            val list = view?.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)
            val arrayAdapter =
                ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songList)
            list?.adapter = arrayAdapter
    }
```

The problem is in declaring values, I guess.

What should I change to make this whole thing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are wrong with your code :

- You don't actually call the url, you are just defining it without opening a connection with a `HttpUrlConnection`
- You are updating UI code in `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute()` which is a background thread, you should always update UI on UI thread
- It's just about optimisation but you better use `RecylerView` instead of `ListView`and **dataBinding** instead of **view reference** and you shouldn't have UI code and background code in same class

With that said a correct way to implement your function using anonymous `asyncTask` would be :

```
private fun getSongList() {
        val task = object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Array<String>>() {
            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Array<String> {
                val url = URL("https://vivalaresistance.ru/radio/stuff/vlrradiobot.php?type=getPlaylist")
                val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.requestMethod = "GET"
                connection.connect()
    
                val songList = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream))
                    
    
                connection.disconnect()
                return songList
                    .readText()
                    .replace("и&#774;", "й")
                    .replace("И&#774;", "Й")
                    .split("\n").toTypedArray()
            }
    
            override fun onPostExecute(result: Array<String>) {
                val list = view?.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)
                val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result)
                list?.adapter = arrayAdapter
            }
        }
        task.execute()
    }
```

Assuming that you want to perform **split/replace** operations on the result and not the url itself

Comment: It is working, thanks. But how do I change charset here? Charset.forName doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MikhailK you could do this by passing it as parameter in BufferedReaderlike :
`BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream, Charsets.UTF_8))`.
Please mark answer at approved if it solved your problem.